# Razor view with CSS ignore <p></p>

Tags: asp.net, css, razor

I have a problem with CSS and Razor view that i can't explain. In my project i have two views with same structure and use the same CSS. In one view all the paragraphes are OK everything work well but in the second view if some label are empty i have two paragraphes in the same line.

My working View :

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/defaultR.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<div class="form_demande">
   //some div
<div class="form_content">
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Nom") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Nom)
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Prénom") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Prenom)
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Service") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Departement)
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Date début ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Debut
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Date fin ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Fin
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Date reprise ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Reprise
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("NombreJours ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.NombreJours
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Reliquat ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Reliquat
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Interim ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Interim
    </p>        
</div>
```

The view with inline paragraphes:

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Template/defaultR.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <div class="form_demande">
 //some div
<div class="form_content">
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Nom") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Nom)
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Prénom") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Prenom)
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Service") :
        </span>
        @Html.Label(Model.Departement)
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Motif de l'abscence") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Motif
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Jours Ouvrables") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.JoursOuvrables
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Durée de l'abscence") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Duree
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Du ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Depart
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Au ") :
        </span>
        @ViewBag.Retour
    </p>
</div>
```

The Css for form_content:

```
 .form_demande {
margin: 15px;
font-size: 18px;
width: 600px;
}
.form_demande span {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
}
.form_demande p {
    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.form_demande p, blockquote, ul, ol {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.form_content {
margin-top: 90px;
}
```

This is the result :

[image: Two views side by side]

**NOTE : If i fill all the data in the view, everything is ok**

Comment: Hi i just edit my post with the css section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css:

```
.form_demande p{
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: It worked well, i to add clear: left to form_demande class. Can you please give me additionnal information about this. Because i can't understand why it's working on one view and not the other.

Comment: clear: left specifies that no floating elements should show on left side, it was not working for another view because in case of empty is shows other data you are showing in label so this property is restricting that don't show anything on left.